# AWS node.js not creating S3 bucket?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use the basic tutorial to create an S3 bucket as follows

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');

AWS.config.loadFromPath('./myawsconfig.json');
AWS.config.update({region: 'eu-west-1'});

var s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.client.createBucket({Bucket: 'pBucket'}, function() {
  var data = {Bucket: 'pBucket', Key: 'myKey', Body: 'Hello!'};
  s3.client.putObject(data, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
    }
  });
});
```

But I'm receiving the following error

```
node createbucket.js
Error uploading data:  { [NoSuchBucket: The specified bucket does not exist]
  message: 'The specified bucket does not exist',
  code: 'NoSuchBucket',
  name: 'NoSuchBucket',
  statusCode: 404,
  retryable: false }
```

Comment: Are you sure your token is being validated and that your bucket name is unique across ALL of S3?

Comment: I just changed the bucket name in my code to be one which is definitely unique. I'm not certain my token is being validated but assumed I'd receive an error saying as much if that was the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into this problem, apparently the Node.js tutorial code doesn't compile. I got a var Object doesn't have createBucket method.

This worked:

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.loadFromPath('./credentials.json');
// Set your region for future requests.
AWS.config.update({region: 'us-east-1'});
// Create a bucket and put something in it.
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.client.createBucket({Bucket: 'hackathon-test'}, function() {
  var data = {Bucket: 'hackathon-test', Key: 'myKey', Body: 'Hello!'};
  s3.client.putObject(data, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error uploading data: ", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Successfully uploaded data to myBucket/myKey");
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: AWS node.js S3 tutorial to be specific

Comment: It's funny, cuz the answer code looks identical to the problem code except for the config .json filename, region, and bucket name. What was the actual problem?

Comment: I think the way the bucket was configured on the S3 side changed things. There needs to be a read/write permission set for the account token info. I don't think the code actually changed anything but i'm not sure

Comment: Compared to the official tutorial on AWS, I had to change two things: 1- Drop region setting, 2- use s3.client instead of s3

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue, discovering that my api-user didn't have permission to create the bucket.

Slightly more thorough error checking revealed this...

```
s3.client.createBucket({Bucket: 'someBucket'}, function(err) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error creating bucket: ", err);
    } else {
      console.log("Successfully created bucket 'someBucket'");
    }
// ...
```

Answer (score 0):

According to aws S3 bucket name restrictions.
your bucket name shouldn't contain any uppercase letter. so 'pBucket' is invalid.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html

**The rules for DNS-compliant bucket names are:**

- Bucket names must be at least 3 and no more than 63 characters long.
- Bucket names must be a series of one or more labels. Adjacent labels are separated by a single period (.). Bucket names can contain
  lowercase letters, numbers, and hyphens. Each label must start and end
  with a lowercase letter or a number.
- Bucket names must not be
  formatted as an IP address (e.g., 192.168.5.4).
- When using virtual
  hosted–style buckets with SSL, the SSL wild card certificate only
  matches buckets that do not contain periods. To work around this, use
  HTTP or write your own certificate verification logic.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of pointers that I missed and someone may find useful

- if you set the region as part of the S3 object `var s3 = new AWS.S3({region: 'us-west-1'});` then the call will fail (in my experience).
- You can therefore set the region via either

a) `AWS.config.update({ region: 'eu-west-1' });`

b) as part of the params on createBucket

`s3.createBucket({
    Bucket: bucketName,
    CreateBucketConfiguration: {
      LocationConstraint: "eu-west-1"
    }
  }, function () {`

also, watch out for caps or underscores in the bucket name as that took an hour of my life too (DNS compliant only).